# Slicing a tensor by an index tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have two following tensors (note that they are **both** **Tensorflow tensors** which means they are still virtually symbolic at the time I construct the following slicing op before I launch a `tf.Session()`):

- `params`: has shape (64,784, 256)
- `indices`: has shape (64, 784)

and I want to construct an op that returns the following tensor:

- `output`: has shape (64,784) where

`output[i,j] = params_tensor[i,j, indices[i,j] ]`

What is the most efficient way in Tensorflow to do so?

ps: I tried with `tf.gather` but couldn't make use of it to perform the operation I described above.

Many thanks.
-Bests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get exactly what you want using `tf.gather_nd`.  The final expression is:

```
tf.gather_nd(params, tf.stack([tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(indices)[0]), 1), [1, tf.shape(indices)[1]]), tf.transpose(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(tf.shape(indices)[1]), 1), [1, tf.shape(indices)[0]])), indices], 2))
```

---

This expression has the following explanation:

- `tf.gather_nd` does what you expected and uses the indices to gather the output from the params
- `tf.stack` combines three separate tensors, the last of which is the indices.  The first two tensors specify the ordering of the first two dimensions (axis 0 and axis 1 of params/indices)

  - For the example provided, this ordering  is simply 0, 1, 2, ..., 63 for axis 0, and 0, 1, 2, ... 783 for axis 1.  These sequences are obtained with `tf.range(tf.shape(indices)[0])` and `tf.range(tf.shape(indices)[1])`, respectively.
  - For the example provided, indices has shape (64, 784).  The other two tensors from the last point above need to have this same shape in order to be combined with `tf.stack`

    - First, an additional dimension/axis is added to each of the two sequences using `tf.expand_dims`.
    - The use of `tf.tile` and `tf.transpose` can be shown by example: Assume the first two axes of params and index have shape (5,3).  We want the first tensor to be:

      ```
      [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]
      ```

      We want the second tensor to be:

      ```
      [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
      ```

      These two tensors almost function like specifying the coordinates in a grid for the associated indices.
- The final part of `tf.stack` combines the three tensors on a new third axis, so that the result has the same 3 axes as params.

---

Keep in mind if you have more or less axes than in the question, you need to modify the number of coordinate-specifying tensors in `tf.stack` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted

Comment: It seems easier to me to flatten the params to (-1, 256) and indices to (-1), use gather_nd, and then unflatten, than tiling

Comment: geez.  that's really clever and also @!@$.  smoke's coming out of my head just reading it.  it's also useful!  thanks.  saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is like a custom reduction function. If you are keeping something like index of maximum value at `indices` then I would suggest using `tf.reduce_max`:

```
max_params = tf.reduce_max(params_tensor, reduction_indices=[2])
```

Otherwise, here is one way to get what you want (Tensor objects are not assignable so we create a 2d list of tensors and pack it using `tf.pack`):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
with tf.Graph().as_default():

    params_tensor = tf.pack(np.random.randint(1,256, [5,5,10]).astype(np.int32))

    indices = tf.pack(np.random.randint(1,10,[5,5]).astype(np.int32))

    output = [ [None for j in range(params_tensor.get_shape()[1])] for i in range(params_tensor.get_shape()[0])]  
    for i in range(params_tensor.get_shape()[0]):
        for j in range(params_tensor.get_shape()[1]):
            output[i][j] = params_tensor[i,j,indices[i,j]]
    output = tf.pack(output)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        params_tensor,indices,output = sess.run([params_tensor,indices,output])

        print params_tensor
        print indices
        print output
```

Comment: Thank for your idea of workaround using `tf.pack` (which is `tf.stack` in tf 1.0). Yes, if tensorflow has some built-in function like `tf.custom_reduce` which selects a tensor by another index tensor, that'd be great.

Comment: But what I want is a more efficient way (slicing) which does not involve `for` loop all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but I recently had to do something similar, and was able to to do it using [Ragged Tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor):

```
output =  tf.gather(params, tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(indices), batch_dims=-1, axis=-1)
```

Hope it helps